# Disable Functions Of 3D Cursor

Tags: 3d-cursor

The 3D cursor is a real pain for me. Is there any way to make it so whenever I select an object, the 3D cursor moves onto it? I hate having a model in one place and having to move the cursor all over to be able to move the model large distances.

I think I recall Blender not relying on the 3D cursor as much in previous versions.

Comment: It's possible to snap cursor to selection using `Shift`+`S` menu. It's strange that you need to move cursor in order to move models, could it be that you activated *3D Cursor* as [Pivot Point](https://www.blender.org/manual/de/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/pivot_point/index.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not supported (although its possible to do this using Python, it would be quite a hack).